# Unity android game lagging while playing on phone

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I was making a normal flappy bird game with simple graphic and when I play it on the unity editor it runs at 180FPS, but on my phone *Samsung Galaxy A71* it runs between 20/35 FPS, what should I do?
I already set the graphic to minimum, but it doesn't work
What should I do?

If you need it these are the two codes that I made

**Graphic Settings**

[image: Graphic Settings]

**tubeManager.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;


public class tubeManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        gameObject.transform.Translate (new Vector2 (-5f, 0f) * Time.deltaTime);

        if (gameObject.transform.position.x <= -5f){
            Vector2 SpawnPos = new Vector2 (5f, Random.Range(-2f, 2f));
            gameObject.transform.position = SpawnPos;
            return;
        }
    }  
}
```

**Profiler View**
https://mega.nz/file/kbMmgDLD#upJ1U8jxIgaKN4KMkvfD_twbLZ9rxlOljizwf4q75J4

[APK Download](https://mega.nz/file/xTFjWL5J#uCLbrpPwKbA5RhZsJVAg2SQH0oks7itICwYwJdhDDGQ)

Comment: PS. it's not the first time that it happens to me

Comment: Always instantiating and then destroying gameObjects, costs quite a bit of performance . I would look into Pooling for this type of game. Instead of instantiating and then destroying the tubes you reuse the same instance every time.

Comment: You can find some [premade libraries](https://github.com/MathewHDYT/Unity-Pool-Manager) this one was made by me a while ago or you can do it yourself or use the base library provided from Unity since version 2021 see this helpful [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EZ2F-TzHYw) from TaroDev.

Comment: If you want to I can write you a more detailed answer, but I think this should help. If you still don't have enough fps you perhaps need to optimize your code further. I would look into the Unity Profiler can be really helpful to see what needs a lot of performance and make sure you don't have any Debug.Log in your final build because thoose really hurt performance on low end devices as well. Hope this helps, good luck on your game :D.

Comment: @IndieGameDev I changed the code but it still giving this problem. Here's the game https://mega.nz/file/xTFjWL5J#uCLbrpPwKbA5RhZsJVAg2SQH0oks7itICwYwJdhDDGQ

Comment: As I wrote in my message above if that is also not the case you would probably need to look into the Profiler, because from an APK and some code alone it is pretty hard to tell what else could be a performance issue. So I'm not sure I can help you anymore than try to show you the possible tools you have at your disposal to find the underlying issue sorry.

Comment: Please do not include meta-commentary in the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit your framerate to 60fps or higher

```
private void Start() {

        Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
    
    }
```

do this even if you didn't create any fps limiter